# Facebook like button does not show

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I am no web developer so please take this as newby question.

I have the simples possible web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>
    Some text
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add Facebook like button to this page following [FB instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator). This is the result:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<p>
    Some text
</p>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/EasyTypeApp" data-width="100" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

No FB button shown. I am testing on localhost, just saving the file as `index.html` and opening it in browser. I found an advice that in such case I need to prefix `//connect.facebook.net...` with `http`. So I made it

```
js.src = "http//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
```

but it still does not work. How do I fix it?

Comment: I think your code has no error.

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy Well, if so can you try it in your browser and tell me if you can see the Like button? I have had no luck with 3 different browsers...

Comment: Can you chek your network access log from console window

Comment: you can see this http://uttamkumarroy.com/demo/facebook_like.php

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy Thank you. I will just buy hosting (would have to do that anyway) and try it there.

Comment: @UttamKumarRoy It works after put on hosting. Should you make this an answer I will accept it.